# Vaadin: when does a binder actually write to a bean?

Tags: vaadin

I am fighting with Vaadin's binder! I have two issues - here is my first:

When is a binder actually updating the underlying bean?

In my form I have added a "Revert"-button which triggers a `binder.readBean()`. The intended purpose of which is, that - if a user decides that some change was not good - pushing that button would allow to restore the previous values of the form.

But here - even though `binder.writeBean()` is never called in the process (I have added log-statements to each call!) the value in the bean has obviously been changed and the `binder.readBean()` does NOT bring back the previous values! What am I missing here?

My understanding so far was that only once I did a `binder.writeBean()` the underlying bean is actually updated with the new values. Is that not so?

I am using v23.1.7

Comment: What type are those fields of? Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out when the value is written, you can run your application in debug mode and set a breakpoint in one of the bean's setter methods.

You aren't sharing a minimal reproducible example, but I would guess that the reason for your problems is that you're initially providing the bean to the binder using `setBean`. When you do that, `Binder` will update the bean every time a field is changed by the user. If you instead use `readBean`, then `Binder` will not directly update the bean but instead wait for an update to be explicitly triggered through `writeBean`.

Comment: Bingo! Changing my initial `setBean(...)` to `readBean(...)` resolved the issue. I can now click on "Revert" after having changed something and all the prior values are refilled - as expected/intended. I hadn't been aware of that difference. Thanks a lot!